# Finding the largest palindrome number

Tags: c

Firstly I'm a new coder. I am trying to find the largest palindrome made from the product of two-3 digit integer which I found on Project Euler-Problem 4. I've written some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int i,num,k;
    int sum, j=1, palindrome = 0;
    num = 999*999;
    i = n = num;
        while(!palindrome){
            for(i=999*999; i>10000; i--){
                sum = 0;
                num = i;
                while(num!=0){
                    k = num%10;
                    sum = sum*10 + k;
                    num /= 10;
                }
                if(i==sum){
                    printf("\nThe Number is a palindrome ");
                    palindrome = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d", sum);

        return 0;
}
```

But it seems to give me the wrong result.It gives the result 997799. I searched in the internet, the result should be 906609. Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(n==sum){
```

What is `n`? You initialize it to `999*999` at the top of the program and then never change it again. Perhaps you mean `i`?

```
if(i==sum){
```

Now the program prints `997799`, a proper palindrome.

---

Note, though, that there's no check that `sum` is the product of two three-digit numbers. Your current approach of starting at a high number and decrementing `i` by 1 each iteration won't really work. You really need two variables and two loops to iterate over the two three-digit numbers.

But two loops will make it noticeably more difficult to find the *largest* palindrome. Oh dear.

```
for (int a = 100; a <= 999; a++) {
    for (int b = 100; b <= 999; b++) {
        int n = a * b;

        // n is the product of two three digit numbers.
        // check: is it a palindrome?
        // check: is it the *largest* palindrome?
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I just checked it out, It would be very helpful if you give me some hint to check weather num is a product of 3 digit number.

Comment: @ZihadFahami Given N and a 3-digit number M, you can compute the quotient with `N/M`, and you can compute the remainder with `N%M`. If the remainder is 0, and the quotient is between 100 and 999, then N is the product of two 3-digit numbers.